# U.are.U 4500 addSensorListener not working

Tags: java

I have tried testing my sample code against a uareu 4500 fingerprint device, and I get the alert for when the reader is connected and when it is disconnected, but not when a finger is placed on the sensor. The reader works perfectly well when tested with c++ codes, but not java codes. Please any advice. 
Please, find the codes below:

```
package application1;

import com.digitalpersona.onetouch.DPFPGlobal;
import com.digitalpersona.onetouch.capture.DPFPCapture;
import com.digitalpersona.onetouch.capture.DPFPCapturePriority;
import com.digitalpersona.onetouch.capture.event.DPFPDataEvent;
import com.digitalpersona.onetouch.capture.event.DPFPErrorEvent;
import com.digitalpersona.onetouch.capture.event.DPFPErrorListener;
import com.digitalpersona.onetouch.capture.event.DPFPImageQualityEvent;
import com.digitalpersona.onetouch.capture.event.DPFPImageQualityListener;
import com.digitalpersona.onetouch.capture.event.DPFPReaderStatusEvent;
import com.digitalpersona.onetouch.capture.event.DPFPReaderStatusListener;
import com.digitalpersona.onetouch.capture.event.DPFPSensorEvent;
import com.digitalpersona.onetouch.capture.event.DPFPSensorListener;
import com.digitalpersona.onetouch.readers.DPFPReadersCollection;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author uncle-samba
 */
public class Application1 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        DPFPReadersCollection readers = DPFPGlobal.getReadersFactory().getReaders();
        DPFPCapture capture = DPFPGlobal.getCaptureFactory().createCapture();
        capture.setReaderSerialNumber(readers.get(0).getSerialNumber());
        capture.setPriority(DPFPCapturePriority.CAPTURE_PRIORITY_HIGH);
        capture.startCapture();

        capture.addDataListener((DPFPDataEvent dpfpde) -> {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Aquired", "Data Aquired", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        });

        capture.addErrorListener(new DPFPErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void errorOccured(DPFPErrorEvent dpfpee) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: "+ dpfpee.getError().getErrorText(), "Error Occured", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }

            @Override
            public void exceptionCaught(DPFPErrorEvent dpfpee) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: "+ dpfpee.getError().getErrorText(), "Exception Caught", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        });

        capture.addImageQualityListener(new DPFPImageQualityListener() {
            @Override
            public void onImageQuality(DPFPImageQualityEvent dpfpq) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Image Quality", "onImageQuality", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        });

        capture.addReaderStatusListener(new DPFPReaderStatusListener() {
            @Override
            public void readerConnected(DPFPReaderStatusEvent dpfprs) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Reader Connected", "Reader Status", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }

            @Override
            public void readerDisconnected(DPFPReaderStatusEvent dpfprs) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Reader disconnected", "Reader Status", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        });

        capture.addSensorListener(new DPFPSensorListener() {
            @Override
            public void fingerTouched(DPFPSensorEvent dpfpse) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Finger Touched", "Sensor", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }

            @Override
            public void fingerGone(DPFPSensorEvent dpfpse) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Finger Gone", "Sensor", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }

            @Override
            public void imageAcquired(DPFPSensorEvent dpfpse) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Image Aquired", "Sensor", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        });
    }

}
```